# Interpretation of this regular expression: (1*0*)*

Tags: regular-expressions

Do the values of the two * inside the ( ) need to remain unchanged for every repetition of ( )?

For example, 110011001100 is part of this language set, but 1100100010 isn't?

Or can the values of the two * change for every repetition of the ( )?

Comment: @HendrikJan Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1):

For any two words $w_1$ and $w_2$, the regular expression $\texttt{((}w_1\texttt{)*(}w_2\texttt{)*)*}$ is equivalent to $\texttt{(}w_1\texttt{|}w_2\texttt{)*}$. Hence, both your examples are elements of the language generated by $\texttt{(1*0*)*}$.

In this setting, it is impossible to specify $w_1$ and $w_2$ occur equally often with a regular expression (except for a finite number of possibilities). Otherwise, you would be able to generate a non-regular language, in this case $\{ 1^n 0^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}^\ast$.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean (1*0*)^3  = (1*0*)(1*0*)(1*0*)?

Comment: Yes, but that's just how powers of words work. $w^3 = w w w$ for any word $w$ (including when $w$ is a regular expression). I'm not sure how this is relevant to the matter at hand...

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding that (1*0)^3 doesn't only = (1^a0^b)(1^a0^b)(1^a0^b) and can also be (1^a0^b)(1^c0^d)(1^e0^f). Thanks so much for the explanation.

Comment: $\texttt{(1*0)}$ is just a word (i.e., a series of symbols); this means $\texttt{(1*0)}^3 = \texttt{(1*0)(1*0)(1*0)}$, just like $\texttt{1}^3 = \texttt{111}$. Do not mistake a regular expression for the language it represents! A regular expression is just a word; a language is a *set* of words. Writing regex $=$ a set of words is wrong *in a conceptual level*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory in regular expressions. If $R$ is a regular expression, then $R^*$ means "any sequence of strings, each of which matches $R$".  So, in your example of $(1^*0^*)^*$, the outer star means "any sequence of strings, each of which matches $1^*0^*$.  $110$, $1$, $000$ and $11$ all match $1^*0^*$, so $110\,1\,000\,11$ matches $(1^*0^*)^*$.

Indeed, since $1$, $0$ and $\varepsilon$ all match $1^*0^*$, every binary string matches $(1^*0^*)^*$.